# how to Download different mobile phone simulators?

Tags: java-me, mobile, simulator

I have created an application.It works correctly in default simulator of WTK (Sun java wirless toolkit).But it does not correctly in my phone (Which i used for testing purpose).So my friend suggest me to download the different phone simulators from web & test it there.

But i deos not know any site is used for downloading freely mobile phone simulators.Suggest me some sites,or any other source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can download the Emulator from following sites,

[Sprint SDK](http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/develop/mobile_platforms/java_me/javame.jsp)

[Sony Ericsson SDK](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/downloads?cc=gb&lc=en)

[Samsung SDK](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/)

[Motorola SDK](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/sdks/)

[Nokia SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/)

And you can also test your application on Nokia RDA devices. see this site.

[Nokia RDA devices](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/)

Answer (score 1):

They usually come with the phone SDK. For example you have phone simulators in Android SDK and iPhone SDK.

Simply append "SDK" to the phone name on google to find the websites (e.g. Android SDK).

Comment: Hi,  julip guerra im new to J2ME.So please send the details from where i get the phone SDK. help me

Comment: I edited my post. But here is for example the Android SDK which include a simulator: http://developer.android.com/sdk/